# Reduce Set problem to SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, satisfiability

So the problem is, given some set $M = \{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ and a set of subsets $S = \{S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_m\}$ where $S_i \subseteq M$. We want to find some set $X \subseteq M$ such that $|X| \le k$ and $X \cap S_i \neq \emptyset$ for all $S_i \in S$.

My solution, I would take some set $M = \{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and suppose $S_1 = \{x_1,x_2\}$, $S_2 = \{x_2,x_3\}$, $S_3 = \{x_4\}$. I would then transform this to a SAT instance to get:

$\phi = (x_1 \vee x_2) \wedge (x_2 \vee x_3) \wedge (x_4)$

Clearly if $\phi$ is satisfiable then there exists some $X \subseteq M$ however this does not guarantee that $|X| \le k$.

So my question is, how can I reduce this problem further so that $|X| \le k$ in polynomial time?

**EDIT**

I realized there may be an easier way to reduce this to the **set-cover** problem but need confirmation that my idea is correct.

*Will post a new question containing this.*

Comment: http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/astra/ModRef10/papers/Alan%20M.%20Frisch%20and%20Paul%20A.%20Giannoros.%20SAT%20Encodings%20of%20the%20At-Most-k%20Constraint%20-%20ModRef%202010.pdf $\;$

Comment: In case it's helpful: This is even easier to reduce to integer linear programming (ILP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final constraint you need to encode is that $k$ or fewer variables in the set ${x_1, x_2, ..., x_n}$ is set true.  There is a good [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13188/encoding-1-out-of-n-constraint-for-sat-solvers) that outlines several methods for encoding a 1-out-of-$n$ constraint.  Those methods can be extended to fit your constraint.  Using a chain of adder circuits plus a comparison circuit seems the most straightforward method to me.