# Can a propositional threshold connective be expressed by standard connectives?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

We are given a finite set of propositional atoms $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ and an integer $k$.
Can we capture through a propositional formula $\varphi$ (built from the standard connectives $\neg, \wedge, \vee$ only) the set of all models having at most $k$ atoms valued at $1$, such that the size of $\varphi$ is polynomial w.r.t. $n$? If yes, how?

The only way I see is to define $\varphi$ as an exponential-sized DNF formula containing $\binom{n}{k}$ conjunctions of literals. For instance, for n=5 and k=2, the corresponding formula would be $(\neg x_1 \wedge \neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_3) \vee (\neg x_1 \wedge \neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_4) \vee (\neg x_1 \wedge \neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_5) \vee (\neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_3 \wedge \neg x_4) \vee (\neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_3 \wedge \neg x_5) \vee \dots$

I got the following comment for the same question on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ but I do not have the level to understand it. I googled all keywords but I still cannot find the answer.

> $d_H(\omega, \omega')$ equals the number of 1 bits in the pointwise XOR of $\omega$ and $\omega'$. So, compute the XORs, count the number of 1 bits, and compare the result to k. It is well known that one can count bits with log-depth circuits (hence polynomial-size formulas), and one easy way to do that is to sum the individual bits using repeated 3-to-2 carry-save addition. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-save_adder if you don’t know what that is. The choice of the basis of connectives is immaterial in all this, as long as it is complete

Comment: Intuitively, I would express it as an exponential sized DNF formula containing $\binom{n}{k}$ conjonctions of literals. For instance, for $n=5$ and $k=2$, the corresponding formula would be $(\neg x_1 \wedge \neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_3) \vee (\neg x_1 \wedge \neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_4) \vee (\neg x_1 \wedge \neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_5) \vee (\neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_3 \wedge \neg x_4) \vee \dots$ I do not see a more succinct way to do it. I have asked the question on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com, but the question seems not appropriate there. The answer may be obvious, but not to me...

Comment: The initial question is here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29389/propositional-formula-whose-models-correspond-to-a-ball-centered-in-some-proposi?noredirect=1#comment69076_29389 but I cannot understand the explanation. What about the specific case when n=5 and k=2 as above, for instance?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempts and information you got.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding 1-out-of-n constraint for SAT solvers](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13188/encoding-1-out-of-n-constraint-for-sat-solvers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use the following steps:

1. Construct an NC<sup>1</sup> circuit computing the binary representation of $x_1+\cdots+x_n$, see for example [these lecture notes](http://users-cs.au.dk/arnsfelt/CT08/scribenotes/lecture8.pdf) (Theorem 7). This circuit implements carry-save addition.
2. Convert the NC<sup>1</sup> circuit to a polynomial size formula, see for example [these lecture notes](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dieter/Courses/2007s-CS810/Scribes/PS/lecture10.ps) (Proposition 1).
3. For each $k$, it is now easy to construct a polynomial size formula that tests whether $x_1+\cdots+x_n=k$.
4. Use up to $n$ of the formulas from the previous step to come up with your desired formula.

You can in fact implement the last two steps more efficiently, using $\log n$ rather $n$ copies of the preceding formula, by using a comparison gadget; details left to you.