# Efficient algorithm for simple constraint satisfaction problem

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, satisfiability, integer-programming, constraint-satisfaction

There are

- $k$ **Boolean** variables $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k$.
- $m$ arbitrary subsets of these variables such that sum of each set equals to $1$ (i.e., only one variable is $1$, the others are $0$). E.g., one of $m$ constraints may be $x_1 + x_3 + x_5 + x_6 = 1$.
- $n$ arbitrary subsets of these variables such that sum of each set is at least $1$ (i.e., at least one of the variables should be $1$). E.g., one of $n$ constraints may be $x_1 + x_6 + x_8 \geq 1$.

The solutions are not necessary, but I want to know **how many solutions exist**.

What is an efficient way to calculate the number of solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is unlikely to be any efficient algorithm.

Your first class of constraints are monotone [exactly-1 CNF clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Exactly-1_3-satisfiability).  Your second class of constraints are monotone [CNF clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).  The monotone part indicates that negated literals aren't allowed (you can't have $x_1 - x_3 = 1$ or $x_1 - x_4 \ge 1$).

Thus, in the special case where you have only type-2 constraints, the problem becomes #monotone-SAT.  Unfortunately, this problem is known to be hard.  [#SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-SAT) is #P-complete, and monotone #SAT is #P-complete as well: it is #P-complete even for monotone 2CNF clauses (i.e., type-2 constraints with only two variables).   It is also known that it is NP-hard to approximate the number of solutions.  As a result, there is unlikely to be any  efficient solution unless the number of variables and constraints is fairly small.  Of course, your problem (with a mixture of type-1 and type-2 constraints) is potentially even harder.

So what can you do, to make the best of the situation?

One approach is to code this as an instance of #SAT, and try applying some off-the-shelf #SAT solver.  You can encode type-1 constraints in SAT using the methods described at [Encoding 1-out-of-n constraint for SAT solvers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13188/755).

Or, you could express the constraints as a BDD and then apply model-counting methods for BDDs.  I expect this to perform worse than a #SAT solver, but you could try it.

Another approach is to use an approximation algorithm.  There are existing algorithms for approximate-#SAT, though they too will hit a limit if you have too many variables and/or clauses.

Comment: His ​ "second class of constraints are" ​ _monotone_ CNF clauses. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, Oh!  You are absolutely right -- I missed that negative literals aren't allowed.  I've edited the answer accordingly -- thank you!

Comment: The negation of x can easily encoded with x+y=1. Then y is the negation of x.

Comment: Nice answer.  One extra point is that Exact Cover can be straightforwardly encoded using only type-1 constraints (basically, for each ground set element, make an exactly-1 constraint listing the sets that contain this element), which means that it's NP-hard to even decide whether there are *any* solutions to this problem (in fact, to the special cases consisting of only type-1 constraints).