# Faster finding of a subset of bits with all combinations in the bitstrings

Tags: combinatorics, bit-manipulation

Assume that I have a bunch of bitsets (strings on $\{0,1\}$) of the same length, e.g.:

```
101110001
001001101
010101010
101001001
101010101
```

I want to find the largest set of bits (indices, not necessarily consecutive) that takes all possible values in these bitsets. In the example above:

```
101|11|0001
001|00|1101
010|10|1010
101|00|1001
101|01|0101
```

the fourth and the fifth bits take all possible combinations `00` (2nd bitset), `01` (5th), `10` (3rd), `11` (1st), so they fit. Clearly, there is no set of bits of length $3$ that takes all possible values (in this case, we only have 5 bitsets, so it's impossible to get $2^3=8$ combinations), so bits $4$ and $5$ answer the question.

I have a lot of bitstrings ($3 \cdot 10^7$) and bits ($100$), and the answer has $\approx 10$ bits, so brute force is out of the question. Based on how the bitstrings are generated, there is a lot of permutational symmetry, so some simple prunings (e.g. if bit $i$ only takes value $1$ (and never takes value $0$), then we never consider any set of bits containing $i$) probably won't work.  What can I do?

As an easier version, I'm also interested in the case when there are $3 \cdot 10^5$ bitstrings, $60$ bits, and the answer is $\approx 8$. For this, I'm currently running the bruteforce, and, assuming that the answer is $8$, I expect that computation to finish in a few days (I know that there is a set of size $8$, and I expect and need to show that there is no set of size $9$).

Answer (score 1):

This problem sounds very hard, especially at the scale you're dealing with.

One approach might be to try using a SAT solver.  I don't know whether this will be even remotely feasible to solve with SAT, but you could give it a try.

Let boolean variable $x_{j,k}$ represent whether bit index $j$ is the $k$th one selected (for $j=1,\dots,60$ and $k=1,\dots,8$).  Let $y_{s,\ell}$ (for $s \in \{0,1\}^8$ and $\ell=0,\dots,\lg(3 \cdot 10^5)$) be boolean variables defined so that $y_{s,0},\dots,y_{s,\lg(3 \cdot 10^5)}$ is the binary representation of an integer $i$ so that the $i$th bitstring has the value $s$ in the selected indices (as determined by the $x$'s).

You can write CNF clauses that represent the conditions for $x,y$ to represent a valid solution to your problem.  In particular:

- For each $k$, exactly one of $x_{1,k},\dots,x_{60,k}$ is true.  (This can be expressed in CNF; see [Encoding 1-out-of-n constraint for SAT solvers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13188/755) .)
- For each $j,j',k,k'$ with $j\ge j'$, $k<k'$, add the clause $\neg x_{j,k} \lor \neg x_{j',k'}$.
- For each $s,i,k$, add the CNF clause

  $$(y_{s,0} \ne i_0) \lor \cdots \lor (y_{s,\lg(3 \cdot 10^5)} \ne i_{\lg(3 \cdot 10^5)}) \lor \bigvee_j x_{j,k}$$

  where $i_0,\dots,i_{\lg(3 \cdot 10^5)}$ is the binary representation of $i$ and $j$ ranges over all bit indices such that the $j$th bit of the $i$th bitstring is equal to $s_k$.  Notice that each term of the form $(y_{s,\ell} \ne i_\ell)$ takes either the form $y_{s,\ell}$ or $\neg y_{s,\ell}$ according to whether $i_\ell$ is 0 or 1, and thus is a known literal in either case, so this does indeed have the form of a CNF clause.

Now run a SAT solver on this problem instance.  This will try to find a combination of 8 bit positions that is a valid solution.  Of course if you try a solution with 8 bit positions, you can next try to find one with 9 bit positions, etc., and if you don't find a solution with 8 bit positions, you can next try to find one with 7 bit positions, etc., iterating to find the maximum number of achievable bit positions.

For your smaller problem instance, we'll obtain a CNF formula with about $2^8 \times 3 \cdot 10^5 \times 8 \approx $ 600 million clauses and about 632 variables.  Each clause will have about 49 literals in it, on average.  This is a monstrously large CNF formula, so I don't know whether a SAT solver will have any hope of finding a satisfying assignment for it, but you could try and see.