# Is Max 3-SAT W[1]-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Is Max 3-SAT a W[1] hard problem, parmeterized by some parmeterize?
I can't find the relevant literature.

I accept any parameterization.

Comment: Is the question whether there exists any parameter at all that makes MaxSat W[1]-hard?

Comment: Like the parameter 1?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Do you accept any parameterization? Or do you mean that max-parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The **W hierarchy** consists of classes of decision problems.  The decision versions of MAX-SAT problems are just slightly disguised SAT problems.  For example, to transform the decision problem "is there a variable assignment that satisfies *k* clauses?", add a unique variable to each CNF clause, then [add a constraint](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143731/reduction-of-k-vertex-cover-to-sat-how-to-define-the-constraint/143737#143737) that demands that at least *k* of the unique variables be set false.  (All this can be done in polynomial time.)  If the resulting SAT instance is satisfiable, the answer to the MAX-SAT problem is yes, otherwise the answer is no.

Since [SAT Karp-reduces to CLIQUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems#The_problems) and [CLIQUE is W[1]-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity#W%5B1%5D), SAT must be as well, and therefore so is the decision version of MAX-SAT.

Comment: SAT Karp-reduces to CLIQUE cannot show that SAT must be  W[1] hard. If clique can reduce to SAT, it is right. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: So MAX SAT is W-hard for what parameter? Also, as an example, vertex cover reduces to clique, yet VC is not W-hard (for the natural parameter).