# How to converts Pseudo boolean constraints to cnf format?

Tags: logic

How to convert Pseudo boolean constraints to CNF format

for example  L1 + … + Ln ≥ 1 is  converted to L1 ∨ … ∨ Ln

but how about:

L1 + … + Ln ≥ k

L1 + … + Ln < k

or

L1 + L2 = k

or

2 L1 + 2 L2L3 + L4 ≥ 3

is it there a book that I could read to understand more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [Tseitin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation) to a circuit with [adders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)) and [comparators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator).

For the special case of $L_1 + \dots + L_n \ge k$ (or $\le k$), see [Encoding 1-out-of-n constraint for SAT solvers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13188/755) and  [Reduce the following problem to SAT](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6521/755).